# Is there an ASM to C convertor?

Tags: c, assembly, decompiling

I have a exe written in C and have decompiled it but the output went right over my head. Will I have to learn assembly in order to understand what the exe does or is there another way?

EDIT: The reason I want to know what's in the exe is because I want to rewrite it, with some improvements, nope no interest in the exe itself.

Comment: _"Will I have to learn assembly in order to understand what the exe does"_. It would help a lot at the very least. Which processor architecture and OS is the program for?

Comment: Read this: [convert this ASM to C?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/convert-this-asm-to-c/2099#2099) and post your question there.

Comment: Your question title doesn't represent your question very well. It depends upon what level of understanding of the `exe` you are after. This is a pretty vague question at the moment. If you want to know in detail what the `C` program is trying to do, you need to know ASM. If you want to know how an `exe` is structured and how the OS knows what to do with it, you might need to just study the structure.

Answer (score 2):

> Will I have to learn assembly in order to understand what the exe does?

In short: yes. Many disassemblers like [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/overview.shtml) will offer to convert assembly to C or another higher language, but in most cases it is anything other then readable.

You will have to familiarise yourself with reverse engineering/disassembly to understand how binaries work I am afraid.

Also it will be highly dependable on what source architecture you are working on.

Comment: On top of what Sergey said, a good way to learn is to get the same compiler used to produce the binary (if possible, otherwise get any) and compile simple programs, and analyze the result. This way you'll grasp how compiler-produced assembly looks like, which helps when you're trying to map back from unknown assembly into what the original code might be doing.